# jQuery hiding group of containers that don't match index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have multiple containers like this, each with a string of text within them. However, these containers may have the same string of text as another.

```
<div class="main">one</div>
<div class="main">two</div>
<div class="main">one</div>
<div class="main">three</div>
<div class="main">two</div>
<div class="main">one</div>

<button class="example" id="one">One</button>
<button class="example" id="two">Two</button>
<button class="example" id="three">Three</button>
```

```js
$(".example").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".main").each(function(){
        var example = $(this).find(".example").text();     
        if( example.indexOf(index) >= 0 ){
          // hide every .main container that doesn't contain matching index
        }   
    });
});
```

For this example, I just want to toggle one at a time and show only the selected container based on the button id.

I'm having trouble working out the *not* logic part of hiding all other containers that don't match the index, its the `$(this)` part that's stumping me.

Comment: When pressing the button with `id="one"` you want to hide every `div.main` that doesn't contain the text `"one"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simpler code. [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) select element has spesific text. Use it in [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

```
$(".example").click(function(){
    $(".main").show();
    $(".main:not(:contains("+ this.id +"))").hide();
});
```

Or show/hide in one line:

```
$(".example").click(function(){
    $(".main").show().filter(":not(:contains("+ this.id +"))").hide();
});
```

```js
$(".example").click(function(){
  $(".main").show();
  $(".main:not(:contains("+ this.id +"))").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">one</div>
<div class="main">two</div>
<div class="main">one</div>
<div class="main">three</div>
<div class="main">two</div>
<div class="main">one</div>

<button class="example" id="one">One</button>
<button class="example" id="two">Two</button>
<button class="example" id="three">Three</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".main").each(function() { ... });`

Inside the each, `$(this)` is the current element. So on the first iteration, `$(this)` will give you

```
[ <div class="main">one</div> ]
```

If you use `$(this).text()` it will give you the text. Then you can compare this with your index.

```
$(".main").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() !== index)
    $(this).hide();
}
```